# LINQ to XML. Enumeration yielded no results?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I cannot figure out why `Enumeration does not yield any results`

```vb
Dim Configuration = From Setup In XElement.Load("C:\xml\setup.xml").Elements("settings")
                    Select Setup
For Each Setting As String In Configuration
    'Do something
Next
```

And here is the Xml file located at `C:/xml/setup.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
  <columns>10</columns>
  <rows>3</rows>
  <thumbWidth>1024</thumbWidth>
  <thumbHeight>768</thumbHeight>
  <thumbPadding>40</thumbPadding>
  <videoWidth>181</videoWidth>
  <videoHeight>136</videoHeight>
  <CaptionPosition>top</CaptionPosition>
  <Autoplay>no</Autoplay>
  <Delay>6</Delay>
  <Target>_blank</Target>
</settings>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've called `XElement.Load`, which will return the `settings` element itself. In other words, you're currently looking for elements called `settings` *inside* the `settings` element.

Options:

- Use `XDocument.Load` instead
- Just use the loaded `XElement` itself, instead of calling `Elements` - with the `settings` element being the root element, there can only be one of them anyway.
- Make your XML document have a root element, e.g.

  ```
  <root>
    <settings>
    ...
    </settings>
    <settings>
    ...
    </settings>
  </root>
  ```